# PCB with AC voltages - May earth cross paths with hot/neutral on a different plane?

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-layers

I'm trying to build an AC "transfer" board that will feature:

- 1x DPST switch (hot and neutral will be switched)
- 1x power line filter

Although this is my first time designing a "high voltage" (120/220V) board, I think I could have done worse. The traces are 3mm thick, I set the clearances to 4.5mm, which is way too much according to my calculations, given that the PCB will be enclosed in a case and will live in a "normal" environment. The maximum power draw will be 400W (120V 3,3A, 220V 1,8A). The PCB that I am planning on using is your simple run of the mill 2 layer board, 1oz.

Here's how it looks:

[image: AC Board]

I'm not too big a fan of that earth connection. The C14 receptacle is connected to the chassis, the chassis is connected to the board with one M4 screw.

Would you rather leave it as is or have the two planes cross each other?

Like so:

[image]

Comment: Should be no issues. I have done the same and passed CE certification by external body.

Comment: Remember after that earth wire leaves the chassis of your system it probably goes through 10's of meters of wire before it actually reaches the earth rod. A few mm or cm of trace on your board won't change much about its performance. It will also likely be running parallel to the phase wire for a large part of that distance.

Comment: It’s worth mentioning that you are dealing with mains voltages rather than ‘high voltage’. Mains voltage implies a source that may have transients and noise and will usually invoke specific standards vs ,say, 220VAC that is generated by an inverter on your pcb.